# laravel 7.0 ErrorException Undefined index: user_languages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-middleware

I am trying to run Laravel 7.0 script
i got this error when i run `php artisan serve`

`ErrorException Undefined index: user_languages`

This is the function:

```php
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = 'EN';
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $user = auth()->user();
            $locale = !empty($user->language) ? $user->language : 'EN';
        } else {
            $checkCookie = Cookie::get('user_locale');
                if (!empty($checkCookie)) {
                $locale = $checkCookie;
            }
        }
        $generalSettings = getGeneralSettings();
        $userLanguages = $generalSettings['user_languages'];
        if (!in_array($locale, $userLanguages)) {
            $locale = 'EN';
        }
        \Session::put('locale', mb_strtolower($locale));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I cannot make out where the error comes from and I need help.

i'm new in laravel

Comment: generalSetting does not have user_languages key

Comment: What is `getGeneralSettings()` returning?